# Calculate sum of recyclerview item double values

Tags: android, shopping-cart, android-recyclerview

How can I sum of Recyclerview every row's textview's values and set in subtotal ?
Below is screenshot.

How can I take value of recyclerview adapter's all textview values in arraylist ?

[image]

Comment: Why don't you use model class to  store all value which are displayed on it and then use for loop to get all value and create some of it and then display it  to total

Comment: I already used model class for getting data. In my case I sum of add ons and required with product price and then set it with textview. Now Can you say me that how to set new total of particular product with addons and requireds in model class and get that new price?

Comment: Post the required code snippets.

Comment: You shouldn't add total in your model class. You need to create two model class here. One for product and one for add-on. Then loop through all the product & add-on to display sub-total

Comment: Like other people already said. You should store your product in `model` then use another list of the model to store the final value of each item (price x add-on) before showing in `TextView`. Loop through this model list, not loop through the `RecyclerView`

Comment: Can you give me example @TamHuynh

Comment: How are you even populating the textviews in recyclerview? You must be having that data somewhere in list or array right?

Comment: Can you post your adapter class

Comment: To be fair this question doesn't deserve those -8 upvotes.

Answer (score 2):

First, Having the text with data means that you already have the values and all you need is the path to access it. There are two ways to get the values:

---

1. **Use the data you already have**

This is the easy way. Assuming you have a list of the items that are already displayed on the screen, You can get them all with a loop.

```
int total = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < items.size; i++){
    total = total + items.get(i).price()
}
```

---

2. **Access the `recyclerview` value**

This also will require you to perform a loop accessing the `ViewHolder` of the `recyclerview`

```
int total = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < adapter.getItemCount(); i++){
    TextView text = ((TextView) recyclerView.findViewHolderForAdapterPosition(i)
            .itemView.findViewById(R.id.memeView));
    total = total + Integer.parseInt(text.getText().toString());
}
```

Comment: 2nd number method= when use that code, my app crashed

Answer (score 0):

```
float sum = 0;
Model mymodel;
ArrayList<Model> objects;

public Constructor(Context context, int resource, ArrayList<Model> objects) {
  this.context = context;
  this.resource = resource;
  this.objects = objects;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(Holder holder, int position) {
  mymodel = objects.get(position);

  sum = sum + list.getItem(i).getPrice();
  holder.subTotal.setText(sum);
}
```

Comment: @ Raj  .my question is same but sum keeps increasing.[link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67245065/14253444)

Answer (score -1):

I think your subtotal should be calculate by your data module, and RecyclerView only show your data or change your module data.